# IBM Worklight 6.2 - Bottom white space in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

In IOS 7, there is 20 pixel white space at the bottom of the page. I am using worklight 6.2. I happened to read few other related documents and come to an understanding that this issue has been resolved from worklight 6.0.0.1.

Comment: Hardly enough information. Does it happen in a blank new app, or in *your* app? If it happens in yours, provide a reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little surprised that you encounter this problem at the bottom - I've encountered it at the top but it was because the status bar was on top of the page.

Please check this link out: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574 - this basically says that WL adds some classes with some CSS properties but this does not always work. That's why you have to turn to native code to exactly specify the dimensions of the UIWebView.
In my case:

CSS:

```
#wl_ios7bar {
display: none !important;
}

body.wl_ios7 {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.
    //Lower screen 20px on ios 7
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 18;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 18;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Idan, the space is present in the entire app(all the pages). We are using multipage template. I just joined stackoverflow, I don't have sufficient reputation to post an image. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bArCPqRrPbRXVvNFNjMnhvM2c/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: @ Eusebiu Have already tried this. Gone through an ibm documentat which had the same thing. Already tried this. But still having the same problem, did your issue got resolved after doing this?

Comment: @Sumanth - Yes, that solved my problem but it was on the top. In the picture I see that the iOS status bar is still over your app/page header. You can see the HTML page height using Safari Developer (http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/safaridevelop.htm) so you can see if it's a HTML/CSS issue or a UIWebView issue.